UIMA Ruta flexible annotation with variable sequence order
I am new to UIMA and trying to annotate a sequence based on Dependencies. I want to annotate the governor and dependent, but want to be able to annotate it no matter which of the two comes first in the sequence.
I think my problem currently is the syntax, this is one of the versions I tried:
INT beginPos;
INT endPos;
(Dependency.DependencyType == "xcomp")->{
{beginPos = Math.min{Dependency.Dependent.begin, Dependency.Governor.begin};
LOG("beginPos: " + beginPos);
{endPos = Math.max{Dependency.Dependent.end, Dependency.Governor.end};
//LOG("beginPos: " + beginPos + ", endPos: " + endPos);
{->CREATE(type.annotation.EGPConstruct, "begin" = beginPos, "end" = endPos, "constructID" = 2103)}};};

I get the messages "EarlyExitException" at "{begin", "Expecting SEMI but found =" at "..Pos = Math.min" and "Mismatched Input: {" at "{endPos"
Can someone help me debug this? Thanks!

There are at least two problems in your rules:

this is no valid Ruta syntax: {beginPos = Math.min{Dependency.Dependent.begin, Dependency.Governor.begin}; You cannot use Java code directly in a Ruta rule.
there is a semicolon missing at the end = 2103)}<>};};

As Ruta is a generic script language, there are always different approaches how to solve an annotation task. According to your example above, this could look like:
DECLARE Dependency (STRING DependencyType, Annotation Governor, Annotation Dependent);
DECLARE EGPConstruct(INT constructID);


// mock example
c:CW{-> d:Dependency, d.DependencyType="xcomp",d.Governor=c,d.Dependent=s} s:SW;
s:SW c:CW{-> d:Dependency, d.DependencyType="xcomp",d.Governor=c,d.Dependent=s};


INT beginPos = 0;
INT endPos = 0;

dep:Dependency{dep.DependencyType=="xcomp"} -> {
    g:dep.Governor{-> beginPos=g.begin, endPos=g.end};
    d:dep.Dependent{d.begin<beginPos -> beginPos=d.begin};
    d:dep.Dependent{d.end>endPos -> endPos=d.end};
    dep{-> CREATE(EGPConstruct, "constructID"=1, "begin"=beginPos, "end"=endPos)};
};



Awesome, thanks! I do have a follow-up question: For this construct, I want to make sure that the Governor of this Dependency is in the present tense. I am trying various forms of
(Dependency.DependencyType == "compound:prt" & Dependency.Governor.lemma{MorphologicalFeatures.tense == "pres"})
But can't seem to make it work. The way I see it, the problem is that the MorphologicalFeature is annotated for each token, but the dependency spans over a longer sequence (Governor to Dependent). Is there a way to do this?

I feel like i'm close, though the final step is still missing. Currently the rule looks like this
(MorphologicalFeatures.tense=="pres" & dep:Dependency.DependencyType == "compound:prt")
{-> CREATE(type.annotation.EGPConstruct,
1,
"end"=dep.Dependent.end,
"constructID" =2103)};
But what happens now if there are multiple sequences that fit this rule, for the first one it will take the first token of that one, but the dependent of the second sequence instant of the first sequence. Would be happy for any hint on how to fix that
